# VBA errors in many excel documents sheets

Tags: excel, vba

hello i need help with Visual Basic,
i have some VBA errors in many excel documents so i'm using a code that will run on a file that contains excel documents needs to be fixed, my problem that i need to find and replace multi lines of VBA code, my code will find only single line and replace it, my second problem that if the excel document contains many sheets i will get an error any idea how to solve these 2 issue?

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim strPath As String, strfile As String
Dim strToReplaceWith As String, strToReplace As String
Dim i As Long, j As Long

Dim VBE As Object

strPath = TextBox1.Text & "\"

strfile = Dir(strPath)

While strfile <> ""
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strfile)

    Set VBE = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject

    If VBE.VBComponents.Item(1).Properties("HasPassword").Value = False Then
        If VBE.VBComponents.Count > 0 Then
            For i = 1 To VBE.VBComponents.Count
                VBE.VBComponents.Item(i).Activate

                If VBE.VBE.CodePanes.Item(i).CodeModule.CountOfLines > 0 Then
                    For j = 1 To VBE.VBE.CodePanes.Item(i).CodeModule.CountOfLines
                        If InStr(1, VBE.VBE.CodePanes.Item(i).CodeModule.Lines(j, 1), TextBox2.Text, vbTextCompare) Then
                            strToReplace = VBE.VBE.CodePanes.Item(i).CodeModule.Lines(j, 1)
                            strToReplaceWith = Replace(strToReplace, TextBox2.Text, TextBox3.Text, 1, 1, vbTextCompare)
                            VBE.VBE.CodePanes.Item(i).CodeModule.ReplaceLine j, strToReplaceWith
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    End If

    wb.Close True

    strfile = Dir
Wend
```

Comment: *"I need to find and replace multi lines of VBA code"*, how many lines? how do you know the number of lines to replace from the point that you find your keyword? Is the number of pasted lines always equal to the number of initial lines? You need to provide more info. Also, you don't need to use `VBE.VBE.CodePanes.Item(i).CodeModule`, just use `VBE.VBComponents.Item(i).CodeModule`, and better choose another name for your variable than `VBE`.

Comment: lets say i have a function in my vba code and i want to replace it with another function because the first function is popping an error

Comment: And the keyword appears in the name of the function or anywhere in the body?

Comment: No i want to search for the whole text and try to match it with the same one in my vba code, so if this text consist from 3 lines i want to search for those 3 lines (my function) in my code and replace them with a new functio or another new lines

Comment: follow this example : https://www.google.com.lb/search?q=excel+vba+find+and+replace&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGmbW-5ZLVAhXGthoKHVHZCu0Q_AUIBigB&biw=1366&bih=662#tbm=isch&q=excel+vba+find+and+replace+multi+line&imgrc=-qobR-n0ZpdvjM: